# Logging events in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes

Iam new to Kubernetes , i have to create a logging mechanism which logs various pod lifecycle events happening in Kubernetes Cluster . Can any one tell how shall i proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the ELK stack: Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana (or EFK if using Fluentd). There is a tutorial here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-elasticsearch-kibana/

Unfortunately this is not a trivial. Google the terms above, experiment and learn. Good luck :)

Comment: thanks for your input , cant this be done programatically like creating a hook/handler/listener to a pod lifecycle event , creating a log file and storing it in a particular location ?

Comment: using python or shell scripting ?

Comment: Your question is really broad. Are you looking for something like the output of `kubectl get ev -w`